# How to upload a blob to server using nodejs and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, multer

I have recorded a file. Now I get the recorded file as blob and I want to upload it to server but anytime I make the request I get `400 bad request`. I will really appreciate if I could get help

Here is the record file function with the generated blob

```
record = () => {
let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
let recording = document.getElementById("recording");

this.setState({ loading: true });

let recordingTimeMS = 2000;
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    preview.srcObject = stream;
    preview.captureStream =
      preview.captureStream || preview.mozCaptureStream;
    return new Promise((resolve) => (preview.onplaying = resolve));
  })
  .then(() => this.startRecording(preview.captureStream(), recordingTimeMS))
  .then(async (recordedChunks) => {
    let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
      type: "video/webm",
    });
    recording.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);

    this.sendVideoToAPI(recordedBlob);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

};

This is the function to upload it to server

```
sendVideoToAPI = async (blob) => {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("dataFile", blob);
console.log(blob);
Axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/upload",
  headers: {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
  data: {
    file: formData,
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

};

This is my server.js

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/upload", upload.single("dataFile"), (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file;
  if (!file) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please upload a file." });
  }
  return res.send({ message: "File uploaded successfully.", file });
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Giphy Chat Server is running successfully");
});
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: FormData needs to be sent as body and needs multi-part Content Type header. Access-Control headers are useless in request...server must set those in response when CORS is applicable

Comment: I get same error when I passed the formData....

Answer (score 0):

couple things missing out in the above data which is being sent to server.

1. formdata header is missing.
2. You are complecating things by first appending to dataFile and then again sending that in the file field. I dont know the relevance of the structure you are creating.

Here is my changes to make the upload.

first code to upload to server.

```
    const uploadVideo = useCallback(() => {
    if (recordedChunks.length) {
      const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
        type: "video/webm",
      });
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", blob);
      console.log("blobdata",blob);
      console.log("Request", formData);
      const url = 'http://localhost:8000/upload';

      // Send the POST request using Axios
      Axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", // Include proper headers for FormData
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      setRecordedChunks([]);
    }
  }, [recordedChunks]);
```

and At the server using the multer to store the file as below.

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file;
  console.log("fileData",file);
  if (!file) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please upload a file." });
  }
  return res.send({ message: "File uploaded successfully.", file });
});
```